# Can't import a JSX component into my TSX file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I am building a TypeScript heavy project but I tried to build a component using JSX to import into a TSX file; however when I try to do so it gives me the error that it can't find a declaration for the module

Here is my TSX file:

```
import HText from '@/shared/HText';
import { SelectedPage } from '@/shared/types'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import Carousel from './Carousel';

type Props = {
    setSelectedPage: (value: SelectedPage) => void;
}

const Samskaras = ({setSelectedPage}: Props) => {
  return (
    <section id='samskaras' className='w-full bg-primary-100 py-40'>
        <motion.div
            onViewportEnter={() => setSelectedPage(SelectedPage.Samskaras)}
        >

            <motion.div
                className='mx-auto w-5/6'
                initial="hidden" whileInView="visible" viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.5 }} transition={{ duration: 0.5 }} variants={{ hidden: {opacity: 0, x: -50}, visible: {opacity: 1, x: 0}}}
            >
                <div className='md:w-3/5'>
                    <HText>
                        SAMSKARAS
                    </HText>
                    <p className='py-5'>
                        Fringilla a sed at suspendisse ut enim volutpat. Rhoncus vel est
                        tellus quam porttitor. Mauris velit euismod elementum arcu neque
                        facilisi. Amet semper tortor facilisis metus nibh. Rhoncus sit
                        enim mattis odio in risus nunc.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </motion.div>

            

        </motion.div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Samskaras
```

Here is the JSX file where I built a Carousel component to use in that TSX file above:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper } from "swiper/react";
import 'swiper/css';
import { sliderSettings } from './common.js';
import data from './slider.json';

const Carousel = () => {
  return (
    <div className='p-[1.5rem] w-[100%] overflow-hidden relative'>

        <Swiper {...sliderSettings}>
            {
                data.map((card, i) => (
                    <SwiperSlide key={i}>
                        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-start gap-[0.6rem] p-4 rounded-[10px] max-w-[max-content] m-auto transition-all delay-300 ease-in'>
                            <img src={card.image} alt='samskaras'/>

                            <span>{card.name}</span>

                            <span>{card.description}</span>
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                )) 
            }
        </Swiper>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: You need set `--allowJs` in your typescript configuration

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSX and TSX components inside a project. there is no problems.

[here: it is an example] (https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-darkness-76y77m)

##### jsx components

```
const Header = () =>{
  return(
    <div>Header</div>
  )
}
export default Header;

---------------------------------

import React from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
const data = [
  {
    name: "A",
    image: "url",
    description: ""
  }
];

const Carousel = () => {
  return (
    <div className="p-[1.5rem] w-[100%] overflow-hidden relative">
      <Swiper>
        {data.map((card, i) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={i}>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-start gap-[0.6rem] p-4 rounded-[10px] max-w-[max-content] m-auto transition-all delay-300 ease-in">
              <img src={card.image} alt="samskaras" />

              <span>{card.name}</span>

              <span>{card.description}</span>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

##### tsx component

```
import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Carousel from "./Carousel";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Header />
      <Carousel />
    </div>
  );
}
```